# Nutch crawling the Parent urls even specified the url filters

Tags: nutch

14. I have an issue with my crawl process. In the url-regexfilter.txt I specified the below filter

^+(http|https)://www.abc.com/subdomain

I want to block the parent URL i just want to crawl only the subsubdomains under subdomain. Help me out how to block the parent URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
+^(http|https)://www.abc.com/subdomain
-^(http|https)://www.abc.com/
-^.
```

you can test if rejected or not with this

```
bin/nutch org.apache.nutch.net.URLFilterChecker -filterName urlfilter-regex
```

add your url, if - it's rejected or if + it's ok